# print the page border when compile with xetex command

Tags: xetex, border

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
```

I need to make font Times New Roman so that I used above packages. When I compile with xetex it works but it removes the page border which I created using `\usepackage{tikz}`. the border is like

```
\backgroundsetup{color=black,
                 scale=1,
                 opacity=1,
                 angle=0,
                 contents={
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay]\draw[line width=1pt] ( $(current page.south east) + (-1cm,1cm) $) rectangle ($(current page.north west) + (2.5cm,-1cm) $);}
    }
```

Please help!

Comment: why not just use `showframe`-package to show the border of the textarea?

Comment: Do not use `fontenc` or the T1 encoding with xetex! use `fontspec`  Then you can use your operating system installed Times font.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done using the [`crop`](http://mirror.switch.ch/ftp/mirror/tex/macros/latex/contrib/crop/crop.pdf) package. And for the Times New Roman font, you must compile with XeLaTeX as you are already doing, but instead of the `fontenc` load `fontspec` and select the font using `\selecmainfont{system-font}`, with this you can choose anyfont installed in your system.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[center,frame]{crop}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
Some text in Times New Roman
\end{document}
```

Another fix, with `pgf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\selectmainfont{Times New Roman}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{ \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt} }
{
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
    {%
    logical pages=1,%
    }
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{4pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
    }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
\begin{document}
Some text
\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not work when i compiled with xetex. border is collapsing

Comment: But when i use \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newtxtext} that packages and first compile with PdfTex then compile xeTex. It looks like what i want

Comment: That's funny, in Overleaf worked just fine. I'm editing with another fix. A bit more complex but must work properly. But I assure you the `fontenc` should not be used with XeLaTeX, `fontspec`was design for both Xe and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: Will it works in windows?

Comment: It will work in any operating system running LaTeX! (I use windows, linux and overleaf).

Comment: I use lot of packages with above code. Are there any problems with that if any?

Comment: As far as my knowledge goes, `pgf` has no imcompatibilities. Did it work?

Comment: I spent too much time to solve that but I couldn't. Can you please send your email? then I can send the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45451/discussion-between-guilherme-z-santos-and-arulraj-figurado).

Comment: I uploaded that file.

Comment: please see chat room to avoid long discussion in comments.

Comment: Sorry, where is chat room?

Comment: [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45451/discussion-between-guilherme-z-santos-and-arulraj-figurado)